# How to alter an existing partitioned table to add sub-partitions to it?

Tags: oracle, partitioning, oracle-12c

This forum has helped me earlier on many occasions and now I need someone to help me with this.

I am looking to **convert a pre-existing partitioned (range) table - to sub-partitioned (composite range-list)**.

1) I Range Partitioned an existing table using the query below:

```
alter table PART_TEST 
modify PARTITION BY RANGE (CREATEDATE)
(
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('15-MAY-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('16-MAY-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (maxvalue)) online;
```

2) Then I tried to alter the table to add sub-partitions (list) using the query below:

```
ALTER TABLE PART_TEST
MODIFY PARTITION P1 
ADD SUBPARTITION SP1
VALUES ('1') tablespace TEST_PART;
```

But I see this error:

> Error report - ORA-14253: table is not partitioned by composite
>   partition method
>   14253. 00000 -  "table is not partitioned by Composite Range method"
>   *Cause:    The table in a subpartition maintenance operation (ALTER TABLE
>              EXCHANGE/MODIFY/MOVE/TRUNCATE SUBPARTITION, or ALTER TABLE MODIFY
>              PARTITION ADD/COALESCE SUBPARTITION command must be partitioned
>              by Composite Range method
>   *Action:   Ensure that the table is partitioned by Composite Range method

Below is what I am tasked with,

**Scenario - 1**:
==> I want to have my existing partitions(range) subpartitioned (list) so that my old data is usable. The data in each of my partitions have to be moved to a sub-partition,

**Scenario - 2**: Then revert back to partition level (reverse migrate),
==> I mean the data from all of the sub-partitions within each partition is moved to be at the partition level and no sub-partitions are left in the database.

Is it possible and is there a way to do so?
If so how to implement the above scenarios - convert existing partitions(range) to sub-partitioned (Range-list) - and how to move back the data from sub-partitions to each of its partition back and no-sub partitions are left.

Comment: You can do it with `DBMS_REDEFINITION`. There's an answer on here somewhere that I wrote that details steps

Comment: i didn't find the answer to my question among the 3 of your replies related to DBMS_REDEFINITION

Comment: it would really help if you could help me with the steps.

Comment: there won't be an answer already that is 100% what you need to do. It's a lot of work to answer this in detail, I can't really spend an hour answering the question for you.

Comment: Not clear with requirements and why do go all the trouble to revert back?.Check this link [Move Partition](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/online-move-partitions-and-subpartitions-12cr1) .Hope that gives an idea

Answer (score 1):

## Scenario 1 - redefine the table

Your SQL is adding a sub-partition, not redefining the table.  I suspect you need to redefine the table to have sub-partitions before you can add a sub-partition.

*12.2c+*

The ability to change a non-partitioned table into a partitioned table via `ALTER TABLE` was [introduced in 12.2c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/newft/new-features.html#GUID-D5D9C311-3597-4494-B8DE-CE33EE4FA546).

Looking at the documentation, it appears that you can change a RANGE partitioned table into a RANGE-LIST partition in the same way.  I haven't tried; be cautious; use DEV for practice.

*pre-12.2c*

`DBMS_REDEFINITION` is the *de facto* way of changing a table between non-partitioned and partition designs.

Google is your friend.  But, here is my recommended [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/online-table-redefinition-enhancements-11gr1):

## Scenario 2 - convert back to non-partitioned table.

This requirement perplexes me.  Doing such a massive change, multiple times, is probably a Tell-Tale sign that you have a more serious problem that you should be solving.

Any way, I suspect that the only way to do this is with `DBMS_REDEFINITION`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and useful information.

I could figure out the fix for this error but I do not see any data in the table I used for exchange.
The error we saw earlier was due to - option 3 mentioned in - ORA-14097 At Exchange Partition After Adding Column With Default Value (Doc ID 1334763.1). [ i was adding a purgeid column post IMAGE_RANGE table and I followed the same as mentioned in this doc for the rest of 2 tables]

its difficult to follow DMBS_REDEFINITION.

Comment: These below work without any issue, but
alter table IMAGE_RANGE exchange partition p1 with table IMAGE_T excluding indexes without validation;
alter table IMAGE_RANGE_LIST exchange subpartition p1_s1 with table IMAGE_T excluding indexes without validation; 

but I do not see any partitions nor data when I query the table I created for exchange, 

SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE  FROM user_tab_partitions WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'IMAGE_T';
SELECT PARTITION_NAME,SUBPARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE  FROM ALL_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_OWNER = 'SCHEMA_NAME' AND TABLE_NAME = 'IMAGE_T';